# Excel validation formula referring to another cell

Tags: excel, validation

I have a big, complicated workbook, recalculation takes several seconds . I'm trying to validate (e.g.) [J2] depending on the content of other cells.

I have the logic in another cell, AE2.
`=OR(AD2="",IF(AND(AD2=AD1,G2 = G1, H2 = H1,J2 = "same items"), TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(J2), ROUND(ABS(J2-1),0) = J2-1, FALSE)))`

AE2 displays TRUE or FALSE as I want.
I'm using AE2 to conditionally format J2 and that works as I want.

Ideally, to ease comprehension and maintenance, I'd like the custom validation on J2 to refer to AE2;
Error- Alert Style: `Stop`
Settings Allow: `Custom` Formula: `=AE2`.
That doesn't restrict data entry, you can enter anything with no messages.

I've tried entering the full formula into Settings Formula. It still doesn't restrict data entry, you can enter anything with no messages.

Any hints?

Edited to Add:

Valid entries in J2 depend on other cells.

- Integers > 1 are always valid.
- If `AND(AD2 = AD1,G2 = G1, H2 = H1)` is TRUE then text value `same items` is also valid.

Edited to Add:
The formula given above works if none of AD1, AD2, G1, G2, H1, H2 are blank. I'm beginning to think the calculation of formulae inside a custom data validation differs from that in a worksheet cell. Back to trying

Comment: I guess AE2 returns True or False. Why don't you link J2 to AE2 with a normal formula?

Comment: What do you expect to be valid entries in J2? I think you are using custom incorrectly, when you should probably be using List.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns As I said, AE2 correctly returns TRUE or FALSE indicating the _validity_ of the value in J2, not the actual value. I've tried putting a normal formula `=AE2` into the data validation Formula box. It doesn't work.

Comment: @user20637 Let me get this straight. So in J2 you can only entry integer values over 1?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns No, that would be trivial. As I said I my edit, and as is implemented in the AE2 formula: Valid entries in J2 depend on other cells. 
•Integers > 1 are always valid. 
•If AND(AD2 = AD1,G2 = G1, H2 = H1) is TRUE then the text "same items" is also valid.

Comment: I understand now. I don't know anyway to do this validation data only with Excel. I'm afraid you'll need VBA code to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've used the customized version of data validation and i got something

I used this formula:

```
`=IF(OR(AND(G2=G1;H2=H1;AD2=AD1;J2="same items");AND(J2>1;ISNUMBER(J2)=TRUE;IFERROR(INTEGER(J2)=J2;FALSE)))=TRUE;TRUE;FALSE)=TRUE`
```

I have translated from my spanish version of Excel, so I hope i did not mistake anything, but just in case, got a screenshot where you have to use this formula.

I typed it in the data validation box of `J2`

[image]

And it works for me:

**Case 1: Only integers over 1**
[image]

As you can see in the image above, values less than 2 or not integer are not valid

**Case 2: Text `same items` but only if `AND(AD2 = AD1,G2 = G1, H2 = H1)`**
[image]

As you can see, text value `same items` is accepted because conditions are met

If the conditions are not met, then the text value `same items` cannot be accepted

[image]

**In the image above `H2` is not equal to `H1` so text value `same items` is not accepted**.

Hope you can adapt this to your needs. I never thought you could do this with only Excel, but yeah! I learned something new.

I uploaded the file to mi Gdrive, if you want to check it out.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-ssBJgCHV1nsc91XYRuQXFoIQh1AB7Ca

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. It's effectively the same as my attempt and, as remarked in my second edit, fails if any of AD1, AD2, G1, G2, H1, H2 are blank, in which case it allows any entry. Also terms like `IF(expression = TRUE` are effectively identical to `IF(expression ` so you can save some typing. I think I've found a neater way to do it, which I'll post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different approach worked quite neatly.

First, a correction to my original question: when I said "Integers > 1 are always valid" I meant "Integers > 0 are always valid", that doesn't substantially change anything.

1) "same item" validity
In a spare column (AF) I put the formula to assess whether "same item" is a valid entry
`= AND(AD2 = AD1, G2 = G1, H2 = H1)`.
This had the minor advantage of simplifying the formula in AE2 which now becomes
`=OR(AD2 = "", AND(AF2, J2 = "same items"), IFERROR(ROUND(ABS(J2-1),0) = J2-1, FALSE))`
(thanks to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns for reminding me about `IFERROR`)

2) column of valid items
In another spare column (AH) I listed all the valid entries, including the text "same items" as the first value in the list. This did place an upper limit on valid integers, but in my case a few thousand is plenty (it's numbers of items tested).

3) named range of valid items
Now I created a named range as a formula.  I find formula named ranges very useful and I quite often use this construction to make the range auto-adjust to numbers of used rows.
`n_items  =OFFSET($AH$1, 0,0, COUNTA($AH:$AH))`

4) list validation on target cell
Finally I set the validation on J2 to
Allow: `List`
Source: `=IF($AF2, n_items, OFFSET(n_items,1,0))`

Job done! Minor advantage, users can(when valid) select "same items" via drop-down rather than typing.

I still don't understand the behaviour of my original attempt or that of @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, but I've found a solution which works for me and don't currently have time to go down that rabbit hole :-{